# Error converting from Rmarkdown to PDF LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pythontex, rmarkdown

I am using `Rmarkdown` using `Rstudio` to generate PDF documents via `tex`. In the markdown, I write the `python` code chunk for reproducibility. However, I get the following error.

```
Quitting from lines 23-30 (A4.4.Rmd) 
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 24, in _import_hook
    level=level
Calls: <Anonymous> ... py_capture_output -> force -> <Anonymous> -> py_call_impl
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
```

It compiles and generates PDF when written in `R` code chunks with absolutely no issues.
I use the `Reticulate` package in `Rstudio` for compiling `Python` code chunks.

It is only just when I `knit` to PDF it generates this error. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I figured out the problem. The thing that I was missing in my `python` code chunk is the `knitr` set-up block.

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE, engine.path = list(python = 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe'))
```